# css links colors not coming properly defined as class defination

Tags: css

In this css classes I need to define different colors to links how can I define proper color for link
my css classes are how can i give color to links

```
.red { color:red; }
.blue { color: blue; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to follow this example:

http://www.ssi-developer.net/css/link-colours.shtml

example:

```
<a href="#" class="red">red</a>
<a href="#" class="blue">blue</a>

.red { color:red; } .blue { color: blue; }`
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K7Es2/

```
    $('.yourid').addClass('red').removeClass('blue');
```

The Jquery you need switch the class is as above. Obviously you need to put it in the check for you logic.

Comment: this also don't have mine ans.. because i need to check something and depending that i need to change the color of link

Comment: So what you need to do is define classes of the styles you want, and do some javascript to replace the class depending on your condition.

Comment: i have done all that javascript is done and  i defined two different css classes named as red and blue for this but not able to define link color..

Comment: My example is showing the links as red and blue, I don't understand why you are having a problem?

Comment: Ok edited answer, there is nothing left to say really.

Answer (score 0):

look..use inline style

```
<a href="#" class="red" style="text-decoration:none;color:#FF0000;">red</a>
<a href="#" class="green" style="text-decoration:none;color:#009933;">green</a>
```

Comment: no i cant do this INLINE because i need to check something and depending that i need to change the color of link.

Comment: then use class .red{text-decoration:none;color:#FF0000;}
.green{text-decoration:none;color:#FF0000;} and <a href="#" class="red" >red</a>
 <a href="#" class="green" >green</a>

Comment: man i have only one link whose color i need to change according to condition

Comment: can you please tell us about condition so i can understand and help...thanx

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this..try this code..may be you will like

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.red {text-decoration:none;color:#FF0000;}
.green {text-decoration:none;color:#FF0000;}
.red a:hover{color:#00FF33;}
.green a:hover{color:#00FF33;}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>


<body>
<div>
    <div class="red"><a href="#" class="red">red</a></div>
    <div class="green"><a href="#" class="green">green</a></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```